# Why does input element ignore the directional properties?

Tags: html, css

So I was making some custom style `input` element in HTML and CSS - Link [here](https://codepen.io/radiantshaw/pen/ORvPzm). But the input element doesn't obey all the directional properties which are `top`, `right`, `left` and `bottom`. The only workaround was using the `top` and `left` and `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`. Any ideas why it doesn't obey all the directional properties?

#### Edits

I need the input element to fit its parent container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because inputs are replaced elements. And the algorithm for [Absolutely positioned, replaced elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width) is different than for [Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width):

> 1. The used value of [`width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) is determined as for [inline replaced elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width). [...]
>
> 6. If at this point the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for [...] [`right`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-right) [...] and solve for that value.

And analogous for the height.

So yes, if you want to ignore the intrinsic size you need `width: 100%; height: 100%`.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't ignore it. `left:140px` works perfectly fine, try this codepen I forked and hover those input fields to check.

https://codepen.io/Varin/pen/dpmorN

Comment: I need the `input` element to fill its parent.